# MS Access reference issue with form fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi there this is my goal, I have a for with a start date(start_Date) and end date(end_Date) field and a report which has a crosstab query as a record source. I want to be able to sort the data on my report based on the dates given on the form. I tried 3 different approaches.

1. Running a macro and opening the report with a where condition in which case Access would complain and say "[Reports]![AuditPTETotal]![Date] is not a valid reference"
2. Setting the "where condition" of my report through VBA. Another reference error but this time, it says that my forms fields are invalid.

   ```
     Private Sub ViewReport_Click()

       Dim strWhere As String

       If Not IsNull(Me.start_Date) Then
         strWhere = strWhere & " AND [Reports]![AuditPTETotal]![Date] >=#" & [Forms]! [AuditPTETotals]![start_Date] & "# "
       End If
       If Not IsNull(Me.end_Date) Then
         strWhere = strWhere & " AND [Reports]![AuditPTETotal]![Date] <=#" & [Forms]!   [AuditPTETotals]![end_Date] & "# "
       End If
       DoCmd.OpenReport "AuditPTETotal", acViewNormal, , strWhere

      End Sub
   ```
3. And finally, passing in my forms values into the query. None of these approaches have worked for me and I really need to get this done. I am out of option. Any help would be appreciated.

Query

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![start_Date] DateTime, [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]!   [end_Date] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Sum(ScrapCollection.PTEtotal) AS SumOfPTEtotal
SELECT ScrapCollection.Date, ScrapCollection.regNum
FROM ScrapCollection INNER JOIN (ScrapTireType INNER JOIN ScrapCollectionTireType ON (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID) AND (ScrapTireType.scrapTireTypeID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapTireTypeID)) ON ScrapCollection.scrapCollectionID = ScrapCollectionTireType.scrapCollectionID
WHERE (((ScrapCollection.Date) Between [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![start_Date] And [Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![end_Date]))
GROUP BY ScrapCollection.Date, ScrapCollection.regNum
PIVOT ScrapTireType.description;
```

Comment: You say you wish to sort the date but your code suggests that you wish to filter the date, which do you wish to do? For crosstabs, if you wish to filter using a form, you must include a parameter.

Comment: This `[Reports]![AuditPTETotal]![Date]` suggests that you have a field or control called "Date". Date is a reserved word and should not be used to name objects.

Comment: Essentially, I want my report to only show the records that are between the date range provided by start_Date and end_Date.

Comment: So if I change the generated name for [Reports]![AuditPTETotal]![DateRange] for example that would be acceptable?

Comment: Changed it to DateRange and tried option #1 with the following error "[Forms]![AuditPTETotals]![start_Date] is not a valid field name or expression" Also tried #2 with the same error as before.

Comment: Changing the name "date" is a good idea, but as I said, you also need parameters. I have posted an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit the results of a crosstab by using a form, you must have parameters:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![AForm]![text0] DateTime, [Forms]![AForm]![text2] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count(Table1.AKey) AS CountOfAKey
SELECT Table1.AText
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.ADate) Between [Forms]![AForm]![text0] And [Forms]![AForm]![text2]))
GROUP BY Table1.AText
PIVOT Table1.ADate;
```

Comment: The error message has changed... "The Microsoft Access database engine does not recognize " as a valid field name or expression"

Comment: Also, those ScrapCollection.Date fields I cannot change since it is a customer's database. Could that be the root of my problem?

Comment: No, they are certainly not a good idea, but I have tested your query in outline and it works for me once the spaces here `[Forms]![AuditPTETotals]!   [end_Date]` are removed. Make sure that everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: The spaces aren't there on the actual query they just appeared when I pasted it on the post. Ummm... The query it self returns data for me and it works fine when I leave the dates out on my form but I am wondering if this could have something do do with the fact that the query is cross tabbed. For my regular reports, I do not get this issue.

Comment: I have tested this all the way through and I am getting the expected report.

Comment: Really?! That's great... Would you like to see my form and report in design view maybe that will help?

Comment: Is your control called `end_Date` or `EndDate`?

Comment: end_Date it used to be called EndDate

Comment: Your form suggests otherwise. I am not sure what you think I can do by looking at an image of the form that does not show the proper names?

Comment: Yeah those are the labels. Sorry for the mixup. The unbound fields next to those labels are the Date fields start_Date and end_Date.

Comment: Thanks for the help though I'm sure I'll fix it eventually.

Comment: I do not see what more I can do. Check all you names, simplify, get a simple query that references the form fields working and gradually add on from there.

Comment: I should have said controls, not fields, this is important.